# JAXB and dynamic selection of class to instantiate

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I have xml representation of a configuration as follow.

```
<definitions>
    <definition type="MessageReception"> ... </definition>
    <definition type="MessageProcessing"> ... </definition>
    <definition type="ResponseGeneration"> ... </definition>
</definition>
```

As you can see, the type of definition depends on the attribute "type".
I would like to use JAXB framework to unmarshall this. But I only find examples of JAXB usage with very basic cases, like book with flat attributes like title, author, year...

Is there an easy way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

When you create inner class for "definition" you should mark "type" member with annotation of `@XmlAttribute`.

Here is the basic working demonstration of given xml;

```
public class UnmarshalJaxbDemo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer xmlStr = new StringBuffer( "<definitions>"+
                                    "<definition type=\"MessageReception\"> ... </definition>"+
                                    "<definition type=\"MessageProcessing\"> ... </definition>"+
                                    "<definition type=\"ResponseGeneration\"> ... </definition>"+
                                     "</definitions>" );
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Definitions.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            Definitions definitions = (Definitions) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlStr.toString())));

            for (Definition defitinion : definitions.getDefinition()) {
                System.out.println(defitinion.getType());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Definition {

        @XmlAttribute
        private String type;

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "definitions")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Definitions {
        private List<Definition> definition;

        public List<Definition> getDefinition() {
            return definition;
        }

        public void setDefinition(List<Definition> definition) {
            this.definition = definition;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I realize my question was not specific enough, so I will edit it: I want to instantiate a different subtype of Definition depending on the "type" attribute, that's my conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xsi:type to instruct jaxb on the class to instantiate.
Example:

```
<definitions>
   <definition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="messageReception">
      <receptionField>foo</receptionField>
   </definition>
   <definition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="messageProcessing">
      <processingField>bar</processingField>
   </definition>
   <definition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="responseGeneration">
      <generationField>baz</generationField>
   </definition>
</definitions>

package your.package

class MessageReception {
   // getters and setters omitted
   String receptionField;
}

jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("your.package");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = mJaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
DefinitionList definitionList = (DefinitionList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to try!